# Modifying value of array after finding element with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I want to change a value in an array that holds a struct:

```
SitSpot[] _spots = new SitSpot[4];
```

The struct fields are:

```
struct SitSpot
{
    public SitSpot(Transform spot, bool isOccupied, int id)
    {
        IsOccupied = isOccupied;
        Spot = spot;
        Id = id;
    }

    public bool IsOccupied;
    public Transform Spot;
    public int Id;
}
```

However, when accessing the array element and trying to modify it, the original array element remains unchanged

```
SitSpot spot = _spots.Where(x => x.IsOccupied != true).OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(x.Spot.position, driver.transform.position)).FirstOrDefault();

spot.IsOccupied = true;
```

So it is necessary to find the index of the array element by to modify specified value:

```
SitSpot spot = _spots
    .Where(x => x.IsOccupied != true)
    .OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(x.Spot.position, driver.transform.position))
    .FirstOrDefault();

spot.IsOccupied = true;
int i = Array.FindIndex(_spots, x => x.Id == spot.Id);
_spots[i] = spot;
```

My question is, can I access the element inside the array and modify it directly rather than changing the value and reassigning it?

Comment: Yes you can. Btw. original array remains unchanged, as structs are value types, not reference types.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice in your situation seems not to use LINQ. I propose following

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetOccupied(this SitSpot[] spots, Driver driver)
    {
        int index = -1;
        int distance = int.MaxValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < spots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (spots[i].IsOccupied != true)
            {
                var distance2 = Vector3.Distance(spots[i].Spot.position,
                    driver.transform.position);
                
                if (distance >= distance2)
                {
                    distance = distance2;
                    index = i;
                }
            }
        }
        if (index != -1)
        {
            spots[index].IsOccupied = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i want to ask one additional thing, in the perspective of big O complexity, is your solution and LINQ is similar? i heard that LINQ is very heavy complexity wise

Comment: @BerkeÇakır I am pretty sure that the code in this answer is much more efficient than the LINQ code in your question. It enumerates the source array only once, and it doesn't sort a subset of the source array, using an expensive comparison function, just to find the smallest one.